# Julia intermediate array allocation with dots

Tags: julia

I have a PDE model in which I am trying to reduce allocations. Currently the following line is the biggest source of allocations:

`part2 .= r.*u .+ deriv .+ q .+ u.^3`

`part2`, `deriv`, and `u` are preallocated `Float64` matrices. `r` and `q` are `Float64` numbers.

My understanding was that the use of preallocated left hand side and `.` notation throughout should avoid allocation of intermediate temporary arrays, so why is this line still my biggest source of allocations?

If I replace this line with the following and add another preallocated matrix `part1`, I get zero allocations, but much less readable code.

```
broadcast!(*,part2,u,u,u)
broadcast!(*,part1,r,u)
broadcast!(+,part2,part2,part1,deriv,q)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless your matrices are some non-standard objects that do some weird things the operation you have shown does not allocate:

```
julia> part2 = rand(1000, 1000);

julia> deriv = rand(1000, 1000);

julia> u = rand(1000, 1000);

julia> r, q = rand(2);

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime $part2 .= $r .* $u .+ $deriv .+ $q .+ $u .^ 3;
  1.011 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

(maybe you have used `@time` and seen the allocations that compilation causes when you run the code for the first time?)

Comment: I'm assessing the allocations by running Julia with `---track-allocation=user`, which shows allocations at this line in the .mem file. I was perplexed because as you have shown, running the line alone did now show allocations.

Comment: My experience with .mem files is that they are not always 100% accurate (but I am not an expert in how they are generated so maybe someone better informed could comment).

Comment: You might try using something like Cthulhu.jl to see if there is a hidden type instability happening

Comment: I still haven't found a reason why this line of code should be allocating, so I'm going to conclude that @BogumiłKamiński is correct that the .mem file is inaccurate.